# How to change Prototype class declarations into jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, prototype-programming

I'm working with my Rails 3.1 migration and it's getting harder and harder to keep jquery and prototype living peacefully side by side. I'm investigating a way to change my Prototype-way implemented js-files into jquery format.

I've used heavily prototype-way of declaring classes and sub-classes:

```
// properties are directly passed to `create` method
var Person = Class.create({
  initialize: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  },
  say: function(message) {
    return this.name + ': ' + message;
  }
});

// when subclassing, specify the class you want to inherit from
var Pirate = Class.create(Person, {
  // redefine the speak method
  say: function($super, message) {
    return $super(message) + ', yarr!';
  }
});

var john = new Pirate('Long John');
john.say('ahoy matey');
// -> "Long John: ahoy matey, yarr!"
```

I've read about John Resig's script: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/. Is this the way to go? Or should I choose some other approach?

I have about 15 js-files (one class per file). I'm willing to spend some time for this migration, so I'd like to do it right. Thanks for your professional help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible way to implement your example with plain functions.

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.say = function (message) {
  return this.name + ": " + message;
};

function Pirate(name) {
  this._super = Person.prototype;
  this._super.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}

Pirate.prototype.say = function (message) {
  return this._super.say.apply(this, arguments) + ", yarr!";
};

john = new Pirate("Long John");
john.say("ahoy matey");
```

You'd probably want to extract the inheritance operations into a function, but this gives you the basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit improved version of Jimmy's example. Firstly, I'd add an extra function that helps you to define prototype chain more conveniently. You could also use `Object.create()`, but that is not yet supported in all browsers, so this function should be a bit more bulletproof:

```
// A convenient function to define prototype chain

function inheritPrototype(child, parent) {
  function F(){}
  F.prototype = parent.prototype;
  child.prototype = new F();
  // set the constructor back to the original, explained later
  child.prototype.constructor = child;
}
```

Then define objects. Notice the extra function `setName` which enables us to set the name of the Person. (nevermind that in JS there's **usually** no need for getters/setters). Also notice the extra `inheritPrototype` call after Pirate function has been defined.

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.say = function (message) {
  return this.name + ": " + message;
};

Person.prototype.setName = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};

function Pirate(name) {
  this._super = Person.prototype;
  this._super.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}

inheritPrototype(Pirate, Person);

Pirate.prototype.say = function (message) {
  return this._super.say.apply(this, arguments) + ", yarr!";
};

var john = new Pirate("Long John");
john.say("ahoy matey");
```

This style enables you to automatically call parent's functions, and you don't have to override each and every one of them, if they are the same as their parents'. Also this doesn't stop you from redefining functions that already exist for the parent (in this case `say` is overridden). And remember, all functions are 1-way, meaning that if you override a function in a children, then parent's function remains unchanged. An example:

```
// Should result in John "The Pirate" Long: ahoy matey, yarr! 
// instead of how it was defined in Person 
john.setName('John "The Pirate" Long');
john.say('ahoy matey');

// Notice that even though Pirate redefined say function, it
// still works as defined in Person, if it's called on a Person object
var president = new Person("Obama");
president.say('Vote for me!');
```

Also using this style allows you to check object types, if the  `child.prototype.construtor` was redefined to child (replacing the prototype sets it to parent's constructor function). John is both Person and Pirate (because Pirate inherits from Person). An example:

```
john instanceof Person
> true
john instanceof Pirate
> true
```

Since president is directly a Person object and not a Pirate, the results would be the following:

```
president instanceof Person
> true
president instanceof Pirate
> false
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the idea! I'll go with Jimmy's example and see if I need to add this. Thanks!

Comment: @hade if you intend to implement inheritance, like in your original example, I'd suggest you at least use the `inheritPrototype` function, instead of redefining every function in the child Object. This is the whole idea of prototypal inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has no concept of classes. It is a library which is built to abstract the browser differences and simplify the process of common operations; [DOM manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/), [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), and [event handling](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

Comment: Thanks @Matt for your answer. The lack of classes made me to choose Prototype years ago (I was more comfortable working with classes). Now that Prototype is fading, I'd like to know what's the best way to migrate in my situation.

Comment: @hade: I've never been a fan of *hacking* in Classes in JavaScript. JavaScript should be embraced for the language it is (with prototype inheritance).

Comment: Ok, now that I have polluted my code with Prototype class "hack", how should I get rid of it? How do you keep your js code in order? Do you use a design pattern like Module Pattern (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Dean Edward's Base.js: http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/03/base/

```
var object = new Base;
object.method = function() {
  alert("Hello World!");
};
object.extend({
  method: function() {
    // call the "super" method
    this.base();
    // add some code
    alert("Hello again!");
  }
});
object.method();
// ==> Hello World!
// ==> Hello again!
```

If you call _super directly, you might run into problems if the super method also uses this._super - and then runs as an infinite loop as you always pass the same object as "this".